# Dynamically Export URL Document To Server Using Python

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2, pysftp

I'm writing a script in python and I'm trying to wrap my head around a problem. I've a URL that when opened, downloads a document. I'm trying to write a python script that opens the **https** URL that downloads this document, and automatically send that document to a server I have opened using python's pysftp module.

I can't wrap my head around how to do this... Do you think I'd be able to just do:

```
server.put(urllib.open('https://......./document'))
```

EDIT:
This is the code I've tried before the above doesn't work...

```
download_file = urllib2.urlopen('https://somewebsite.com/file.csv')
file_contents = download_file.read().replace('"', '')
columns = [x.strip() for x in file_contents.split(',')]

# Write Downloaded File Contents To New CSV File
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(columns)

# Upload New File To Server
srv.put('./file.csv', './SERVERFOLDER/file.csv')
```

ALSO:
How would I go about getting a FILE that is ONE DAY old from the server? (Examining age of each file)... using paramiko

Comment: Try and see & then tell us what happened. :)

Comment: Didn't work. I had to use the I did the urllib2.urlopen() into a variable. Then did a read() on it....from there, I parsed it and placed it into a local csv file in which I uploaded to the server....the surely must be a faster, more efficient way.

Comment: It would be convenient if you could provide your code in your question.

Comment: Just updated my question with the code. :)